# Is there a way in python to execute all functions in a file without explicitly calling them?

Tags: python

Is there a library or a python magic that allows me to execute all functions in a file without explicitly calling them. Something very similar to what pytest is doing - running all functions that start with 'test_...' without ever registering them anywhere.

For example assume I have a file a.py:

```
def f1():
    print "f1"

def f2():
    print "f2"
```

and assume I have file - my main file - main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_magic()
```

so when I call:

```
python main.py
```

The output would be:

```
f1
f2
```

Comment: Seems like you might be interested in [metaprogramming](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html).  I've never delved into it so I'd be the last person to tell you how to approach it.

Comment: You can use introspection to find all the functions in the globals and locals dictionary, possibly by going back through the call stack to find the caller's globals/locals.  Look at the `inspect` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
def some_magic():
    import a
    for i in dir(a):
        item = getattr(a,i)
        if callable(item):
            item()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_magic()
```

`dir(a)` retrieves all the attributes of module `a`.  If the attribute is a callable object, call it.  This will call *everything* callable, so you may want to qualify it with `and i.startswith('f')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import inspect
import sys


def f1():
    print("f1")


def f2():
    print("f2")


def some_magic(mod):
    all_functions = inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isfunction)
    for key, value in all_functions:
        if str(inspect.signature(value)) == "()":
            value()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_magic(sys.modules[__name__])
```

It will only call functions that don't have any parameters by using inspect.signature(function).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried callifile?

```
pip install callifile
```

and then, in your file:

```
from callifile.callifile import callifile as callifile
import sys

callifile(module=sys.modules[__name__], verbose=True)
```

## Self-sufficient example:

In a file *some_callify.py*:

```
from callifile.callifile import callifile as callifile
import sys

def f_1():
    print "bla"

callifile(module=sys.modules[__name__], verbose=True)
```

Calling in terminal:

```
python some_callify.py
```

Gives me the terminal output:

```sh
Apply call_all_function_in_this_file on <module '__main__' from 'some_callify.py'>
See if should call callifile
See if should call f_1
Call f_1
bla
```